# Bounds not matching up correctly in summation in `TransformMatchingTex`

Tags: python-3.x, manim

In Manim I am trying to animate the upper bound of a summation changing using `TransformMatchingTex`. As long as the number of digits in the upper bound doesn't change, the animation animates smoothly. However, if the number of digits changes, then it looks like Manim incorrectly matches up elements, and the summation symbol itself takes part in the animation.

```py
class Test(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        super().construct()

        tex1 = MathTex("\\sum_{k=1}^{", "2", "}")
        tex2 = MathTex("\\sum_{k=1}^{", "34", "}")

        self.play(Write(tex1, run_time=0.75))
        self.play(TransformMatchingTex(tex1, tex2, key_map={"2": "34"}))
```

Result:

https://imgur.com/a/uSjpvAa

Of course, what I'd like is for the 2 to just become the 34 — not for the 2 to become the 3, the summation to become the 4, the k to become the summation, etc…

What is the right way to match up terms here? (I'm surprised that the `key_map` didn't solve the problem — what's its purpose if it doesn't fix this?)